# How to repair Puzzle marked as ??? in Puzzle Swap?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, puzzle-swap

At the last StreetPass-exchanges, I saw in Puzzle Swap a puzzle marked as ???. Normally that's a new puzzle, but on the other side I also saw no pieces. I think it can be linked to the new puzzle recently came here in Europe via SpotPass (Kid Icarus I think). I got the message and the new puzzle, but that's no longer available in my puzzles. How can I repair that?

Comment: So are you missing the Kid Icarus puzzle? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I gave up on the puzzles (my heart bleeds) and started it anew. After a day I got via SpotPass the first puzzle with red tiles, and later the Kid Icarus-Puzzle. This time it didn't broke, it was all available in StreetPass-encounters. Only I had to start fresh. :-(

I don't know, why it was broken in the first place, maybe some error while writing the flash-memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see the correct answer here I suppose I'll revive this question...

Certain puzzles are only available in certain regions. If someone you streetpass has a puzzle that is not available to your 3DS's region, it will show as a blank puzzle labelled "???".

For information about which puzzles are available in which regions, see http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Puzzle_Swap.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd, when you get Kid Icarus you should also automatically get 1 random piece for it. Maybe see if you can streetpass with someone who has a piece to that puzzle you can take?

Comment: I got a piece, but the puzzle is vanished now. Also I think the others have parts of the puzzle, but I don't see it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of all of the puzzles that are available as of this posting - if you are missing one, then that might be where your problem is, and you can try to get the puzzle from other people (if they have a puzzle you do not have, it will show on their iist as ???, and you can pick a piece from it to start your puzzle.)

- Metroid: Other M (15 pieces)
- Mario and Bowser (15 pieces)
- Super Mario Galaxy 2 (15 pieces)
- The Legend Of Zelda (15 pieces)
- Kirby's Dream Land (15 pieces)
- Pikmin (15 pieces)
- New Super Mario Bros. Wii (15 pieces)
- Ocarina of Time 3D (24 pieces)
- Star Fox 64 3D (24 pieces)
- Super Mario 3D Land (0 pieces)
- Mario Kart 7 (40 pieces)
- Rhythm Heaven Fever (24 pieces)
- Donkey Kong Country Returns (24 pieces)
- Pilotwings: Resort (24 pieces)
- Kid Icarus: Uprising (40 pieces)

You can also try deactivating StreetPass for the Mii Plaza and reconnecting it (by going into System Settings > Data Management > StreetPass Management > Then select the software you wish to deactivate StreetPass on > Then click on Deactivate StreetPass. After that, go into the Mii Plaza, and it should ask you if you want to activate StreetPass. If that does not happen, there is the option to reactivate it manually in the software's network settings.)

Other than that, there is no real way to force the Mii Plaza to update.

If you still have the message from Nintendo that talks about the update that added Kid Icarus as a puzzle, you can try using that to enter the plaza, maybe it will trigger whatever is missing.